# Solve $\int\ e^x \sin(9x)\,dx$ using integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have this Integration by Parts question that I can't seem to find an answer to.

The question is:

$$\int\ e^x 
\sin(9x)\,dx$$

I used u-substitution:

$$u=e^x,du=e^x\,dx$$
$$dv=\sin(9x)\,dx, v=-\frac{1}{9}\cos(9x)$$

Then I got:

$$-\frac{1}{9}e^x\cos(9x)+\frac{1}{9}\int\ e^x\cos(9x)\,dx$$

After a second integration I used:

$$u=e^x, du=e^x\,dx$$

$$dv=\cos(9x)\,dx, v=\frac{1}{9}\sin(9x)$$

Furthermore,

$$\int\ e^x\sin(9x)dx=-\frac{1}{9}\ e^x\cos(9x)+\frac{1}{9}\left(\frac{1}{9}\ e^x\sin(9x)-\frac{1}{9}\int\ e^x\sin(9x)\,dx\right)$$

$$\int\ e^x\sin(9x)dx=-\frac{1}{9}\ e^x\cos(9x)+\frac{1}{81}\ e^x\sin(9x)-\frac{1}{81}\int\ e^x\sin(9x)\,dx$$

I'm stuck and I'm not sure exactly what to do after this.

Any help would be very grateful..thanks!

Comment: For clear expression of any trigonometric equations, be sure to include \ before cosine and sine.

Answer (score 6):

More simply and without integration by parts we have
$$\int e^x\sin(9x)dx=\operatorname{Im}\int e^{(1+9i)x}dx=\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac1{1+9i}e^{(1+9i)x}\right)=\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac1{82}(1-9i)e^{(1+9i)x}\right)$$

Now develop and take the imaginary part.

Comment: Where did you learn this? I've never seen it answered like that before

Comment: @AlecLeonK First, write $e^{(1 + 9i)x}$ as $e^xe^{9ix}$.  Then, for $e^{9ix}$, use Euler's identity and find the imaginary part of that expression.  For more information about this method, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272089/how-to-integrate-by-using-imaginary-and-real-part-of-eix).

Answer (score 4):

From where you left off, let

$$s = \int e^x\sin(9x)\,dx$$

Then, we have

$$s = -\dfrac{1}{9}e^x\cos(9x) + \dfrac{1}{81}e^x\sin(9x) - \dfrac{1}{81}s$$

Solving for $s$ gives

$$\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{82}{81}s &= -\dfrac{1}{9}e^x\cos(9x) + \dfrac{1}{81}e^x\sin(9x)\\
s &= \dfrac{81}{82}\left(-\dfrac{1}{9}e^x\cos(9x) + \dfrac{1}{81}e^x\sin(9x) \right)\\
\int e^x\sin(9x)\,dx &= \dfrac{81}{82}\left(-\dfrac{1}{9}e^x\cos(9x) + \dfrac{1}{81}e^x\sin(9x) \right)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I typed it in and I see the logic behind it but for some reason it says it's wrong. I understand what you did though.

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that.  I think you ask this question that comes from the online homework, am I right?

Comment: Yes it does, do you know why it might be wrong?

Comment: I don't know.  Assuming your online HW system does not give away answer after exhausted amount of attempts or after HW deadline, I would assume that the HW system computed the integral in the complicated way without using the elementary method you learned (I guessed).

Comment: Would it make a difference if I make the orginal 'u'=sin(9x) instead of e^x?

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$\int e^x\sin(9x)dx=−\frac{1}{9}e^x\cos(9x)+\frac{1}{81} e^x\sin(9x)−\frac{1}{81}\int e^x\sin(9x)dx$$ Then bring $−\frac{1}{81}\int e^x\sin(9x)dx$ to the other side and you get 
$$\frac{82}{81}\int e^x\sin(9x)dx=−\frac{1}{9} e^x\cos(9x)+\frac{1}{81} e^x\sin(9x)$$

Answer (score 2):

We can take a more general approach, and find 
$$I=\int e^{ax}\sin bx\ \mathrm{d}x$$
Integration by parts:
$$\mathrm{d}v=\sin bx\ \mathrm{d}x\Rightarrow v=-\frac1b\cos bx\\u=e^{ax}\Rightarrow \mathrm{d}u=ae^{ax}\mathrm{d}x$$
Plug it in:
$$I=-\frac{e^{ax}}b\cos bx+\frac ab\int e^{ax}\cos bx\ \mathrm{d}x$$
Integration by parts round $2$:
$$\mathrm{d}v=\cos bx\ \mathrm{d}x\Rightarrow v=\frac1b\sin bx\\u=e^{ax}\Rightarrow \mathrm{d}u=ae^{ax}\mathrm{d}x$$
Plug in:
$$I=-\frac{e^{ax}}b\cos bx+\frac ab\bigg(\frac{e^{ax}}{b}\sin bx-\frac ab\int e^{ax}\sin bx\ \mathrm{d}x\bigg)$$
Take note of the $\int e^{ax}\sin bx\ \mathrm{d}x$ term:
$$I=-\frac{e^{ax}}b\cos bx+\frac{ae^{ax}}{b^2}\sin bx-\frac{a^2}{b^2}I$$
$$\bigg(1+\frac{a^2}{b^2}\bigg)I=\frac{e^{ax}}b\bigg(\frac ab\sin bx-\cos bx\bigg)$$
$$I=\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}\frac{e^{ax}}b\bigg(\frac ab\sin bx-\cos bx\bigg)$$
$$I=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\big(a\sin bx-b\cos bx\big)+C$$
Isn't that cool? This is called a reduction formula, and there are many more of them.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that there are several posts about this type of integrals on this site. Such as [Integrate $e^{ax}\sin(bx)?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/540295) (and [other posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/540295)).This post might also be of interest: [Integration by parts: $\int e^{ax}\cos(bx)\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20952) (together with [the linked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20952).)